# How to Store Different Types of "Products" in a database

Tags: sql, database-design

I am developing a database and not how to best store this information in my sql db.

A user can buy a subscription(ie months of access) and buy credits to do certain actions on my site(each action decreases the credits down).

Do I need to make separate tables to store this as, for instance subscription may give them 3 months access but credits would be just a value with a number that would decrease or increase if they buy more.

Comment: I think it would be ideal to create two separate tables for Subscription and Credit and you can manage activities associated with these two separately.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provided until now, I would do the following:

table [customer], fields: customer_id,....

table [subscription], fields: subscription_id,customer_id,start_date,expiration_date,initial_credits
table [action], fields: date,subscription_id,credit_cost,action_type,....

Maybe add a redundunt field of current credits to subscription table if you need it fast.

Comment: I don't get what your action table is  for.